# Where is the .ssh directory?

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10, openssh

[image]

I installed openssh, but I can't find the `.ssh` directory. Could anyone be able to tell me where could I find this directory?

**P.S.** I installed Ubuntu 16.10 as a virtual machine.

Comment: The .ssh directory is not by default created below your home directory. When you call `ssh somehost` (replace 'somehost' by the name or IP of a host running sshd), the directory and the file `.ssh/known_hosts` will be created. Instead, you may create it with `mkdir ~/.ssh`.

Comment: Try restarting the system, and if doesn't work remove __with sudo apt remove__ then __re-install__

Comment: As you have openssh-server installed (and should be running) as well, you just may issue `ssh localhost` and reply `yes` when asked to continue connection.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The file is not created by the installation, but upon the first use of `ssh` or `ssh-keygen`. If it is not there, there is nothing to worry about. You can simply create it using `mkdir ~/.ssh/`.

Comment: Is there an environment variable for changing the location of the .ssh directory?

Comment: @pfincent not for SSH. It reads the user information from the operating system using getpwnam or getpwuid around these lines: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/misc.c#L1171

Answer (score 8):

Check here for the *.ssh* directory in here `/home/your-username/.ssh`.

Its hidden as a result of the **dot(.)** before the name.

So to find it do `ls -a | grep .ssh` in your current location as seen in the image. Also try using *nautilus*

Comment: It doesn't work; watch the new picture in the question.

Comment: if that's the case remove and re-install again, seems odd.

Comment: The reason it didn't work in the picture is because grep .ssh is looking for some character followed by ssh.  Try grep \.ssh

Comment: @grantwparks mine works with `\.ssh` or `.ssh` but best to use the `\` character

Answer (score 3):

You can go to Home and press Ctrl H, you can see a folder called .ssh

Comment: Ctrl-H shows hidden files in the Files app.

Answer (score 0):

Older topic but if anyone else is looking for an answer and got here from a google search..
If you have connected FROM a "username" to a remote machine and accepted the key then you should look for .ssh folder in /home/username ...

**If you don't find the .ssh folder** then you have probably connected from a different user .. for example 'root' , then the .ssh folder is in the root directory /

Hope it helps others :)